# Adding WMS-Maps to the Layer-section in QGIS by making groups and subgroups through Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, wms, layers

I want to add WMS-Maps to the Layer-section in QGIS, where there should be a group and sub-groups with those. The wish is to add the WMS-Maps to the Layer-section and group them at once-time by using Python. For this, I use CRS or URLs of the WMS-Sources. Do not forget: There are many WMS-Maps, let say it as a hundred, they should be ordered by group and subgroups. Of course, the Map-Layers from the WMS would have to be embedded in the Layer-Section of QGIS through Python. Please, would you me help with that?

What I have tried so far is below as you can see.

```
tmpURL=crs='Here comes CRS'

tmpRasterLayer=QgsRasterLayer(tmpURL, 'layer name','wms')
if tmpRasterLayer.isValid():
    print('Alles i.O')

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer = QgsLayerTreeLayer(tmpRasterLayer)
group = root.insertGroup(0, "Group name")
group.insertChildNode(0, layer)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Can you provide a sample of your Python code? You're unlikely to get much, if any, response if you just ask people to write your code for you without showing any effort.

Comment: I just did it. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Do you have a list of WMS sources? You will need something as such to iterate through to achieve this.